# Going to another ViewController in closure does not work in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to go to another ViewController (that is part of a TabBarController) after some networking code has been executed (using AlamoFire, inside a closure). The name of my current VC is StartingVC. I want to go to another VC after my closure has validated some code. In my example, the code is met, I am 100% sure because I have a `println()` that indicates so, but it does not take me to the other VC.

My closure code is the following:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost/test.php", parameters: dataToSend).responseJSON{
                (request, response, data, error) in

self.showViewController(HomeViewController(), sender: nil)
```

I am aware that I need to use `self` inside a closure to refer to the actual VC I am working in. But the code does not work.

Do you know how to present/push/goto another VC using code? I am not using any Storyboard links to my HomeViewController because I had some problems before using a segue both programmatically and in the storyboard, that is why I decided to go for the code approach.

Thank you for you help in advance

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to set navigation controller with storyboard and unable to start with there, your appdelegate should be like:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
//you must mark the window and navigationController variables as optional
var window: UIWindow?
var navigationController: UINavigationController?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

    navigationController = UINavigationController()
    var homeViewController: UIViewController = UIViewController()
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(homeViewController, animated: false)

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController

    self.window.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
}
```

Other than that on view controller you can push view controller with storyboard object as:

```
var firstViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstViewController") as! firstViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(firstViewController, animated: false);
```

Present view controller:

```
let vc = ViewController() //change this to your class name
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Jack, Is that helpful to you?